# Host a website on a LAMP server, but only for whitelisted IP addresses?

Tags: server, apache2, ip

I currently have a home server (running Ubuntu Server headless) that I use for a few applications, like running a Minecraft server I can access remotely, or some rudimentary SSH-ing.

I'd like to test a few things that'd require hosting some files (in this case, .svg files), but, as far as I know, there's a *lot* of security risk in an amateur opening a website up to the internet. I'd be content with allowing only certain IP addresses to access the website via a browser. I've LAMP installed and all that, but how can I open the server to specific IP addresses?

Comment: With `iptables` you could change your default policy to drop and whitelist / accept only connections from IP's you trust. Another solution is to install an OpenVPN-Server and only open the OpenVPN port to the wild. Than each machine, who wants to use services from your server needs to log in via VPN first. That does reduce the attack surface a lot.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Would either of these solutions still allow me to SSH from whatever IP I want (using a public key)? I only want to restrict access to the *website*.

Comment: If you set your default iptables policy to drop you will lock out yourself from SSH except you open the ssh-port antes. You could also enable the ssh port for specific ip / ip-ranges.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Ah, sorry. That's not what I'm looking to do. :(

Comment: *I'd be content with allowing only certain IP addresses to access the website via a browser.* How do you want to achieve restricted access if you do not block unauthorized access? You need to block or exclude if you want to restrict access to specific ip's. The only other way that comes to my ming could be using an htaccess file with authentification. But thats not an IP restriction.

Comment: I am sorry for my posting before. I did not want to be impolite nor to be rude. I did a quick search and found a few postings about Apache to handle ip restrictions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714332/allow-request-coming-from-specific-ip-only | https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264233/apache-block-an-ip-address-from-accessing-the-website#3325317